# JS basic random image select

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I've only started HTML yesterday and I'm trying to do a really basic memory game. First, there's an image of all the pieces, then a button that calls a function that hides that image and make another appear. This second image is a blank page with the spaces where the parts of the former image were. Also, there's an usemap and a function that returns if the player has clicked correctly or not. My problem is to come up with a function (and how to call it) to select a random part of the image.

```
function checkAnswer(a) {
if (a=='6') {
    alert('Correct!')
    }
else {
    alert('Wrong!')
    }
}
```

The 'a' must be a random number and follow the index of the chosen picture.

This is what I've found, but couldn't use:

```
<!-- Attempt of random

function random_imglink() {
var cobras=new Array()
cobras[1]="<img src ="..\images\Cobra1.jpg">"
cobras[2]="..\images\Cobra2.jpg"
cobras[3]="..\images\cobra3.jpg"
cobras[4]="..\images\cobra4.jpg"
cobras[5]="..\images\cobra5.jpg"
cobras[6]="..\images\cobra6.jpg"
cobras[7]="..\images\cobra7.jpg"
cobras[8]="..\images\cobra8.jpg"
cobras[9]="..\images\cobra9.jpg"
cobras[10]="..\images\cobra10.jpg"
cobras[11]="..\images\cobra11.jpg"
cobras[12]="..\images\cobra12.jpg"
cobras[13]="..\images\cobra13.jpg"
cobras[14]="..\images\cobra14.jpg"
cobras[15]="..\images\cobra15.jpg"
var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*cobras.length)
if (ry=='0') {
    ry = '1'
    }
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}

-->

<!-- Attempt of random
<script>

var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = '..\images\Cobra1.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = '..\images\Cobra2.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = '..\images\cobra3.jpg';


function nextImage(element)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src)
        {
            if(i === imgArray.length){
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Did you know that `Math.random()` gives you a number from 0 to 1? If you want to get a number from e.g. 1 to 10, then you need to do `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)`.

Comment: Consider creating the cobras array outside of the random_imglink function.

Comment: What @RotemHarel said plus check the name of your array when you use document.write, it says myImages